# Is it possible to override default QGIS error messages?

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, error

From my QGIS plugin I would like to override/replace one of the the default QGIS error message ("The layer layer_url is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map") with my own message. I have looked at the API and can't find anything along these lines. Is it possible to achieve this?